# Turtle Not Working in Spyder (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, spyder

I'm trying to use Turtle in Spyder and I'm encountering a frustrating situation.
Basically, the first time I compile everything works. When I close Turtle and try and compile again, Spyder will just open a blank screen. The only way to get it to work again is to exit Spyder and reopen it, which is not a fix for my situation.

I read the thread "turtle.done() not working in Spyder" and added the suggestion of "turtle.bye()" at the end of my code, but that does nothing. Any help would be much appreciated! Here's just a simple example below:

```
import turtle
fred = turtle.Pen()
fred.shape("turtle")
fred.forward(100)
turtle.done()
turtle.bye()
```

Comment: How interesting. I can't quite replicate this - I can't even get the blank window on the second attempt.

Comment: Ok, I can get a new, blank, window if I `clear all` in the iPython console. Judging from google searches, you might be out of luck on this one as there seem to be a lot of issues. A workaround, I guess is to have a terminal/cmd open in the same working directory and running your code through that whilst developing in Spyder.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for looking into it for me. I seem to have found a solution that gets the job done:

In Spyder, head to tools -> preferences -> IPython Console -> graphics and where it says backend, switch it to **automatic** (not Tkinter which was what some answers online suggested).

Also, you **must** have turtle.done() and turtle.bye() at the end of your code.

This allows me to compile and see the turtle scuttle around, and then I **have to** close the window and then compile again and it works. That's the only downside - I can't keep the turtle display window open and continually update my code. I have to close it and then compile - much better than restarting Spyder though!

Thanks again!